# How can WCF redirect client's request

Tags: wcf

I need to redirect a client's request from web service A to web service B. The goal here is to update the server side logic only, so that the client can be redirected to web service B seamlessly without updating the url of which web service it should be pointing to.

I can easily turn web service A to the client of web service B so that it acts as a proxy sitting in between of the client and web service B. But our tech lead has turn this option down.

Are there any other ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a really good series on MSDN by Michele Leroux Bustamente on [Building a WCF Routing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx) which seems to be just about what you're trying to do.

For now, in .NET 3.5, you'll have to do all of this yourself. It's a bit of work, but it can definitely be done.

With .NET 4.0 and WCF 4.0, there will be a new routing service built-in (see Christian Weyer's [blog post](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2009/05/08/415335.aspx) on this) that you can use as a base class for your service implementation. It can be configured declaratively (or in code) using routing tables. .NET 4.0 should be out before the end of 2009 (or so Microsoft says for now).

Marc